# JPA - Only primary key is retrieved, other fields returned null

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am new to Java EE.
I am using Eclipse Juno + Eclipse Link + MySQL.
Currently I have a JPA project and a dynamic web project.
The JPA project is included in the web project's build path.
I created a class "StudentDomain" in JPA project to retrieve rows from Student table.
It works **fine** in the JPA project.
But in web project, only ID is returned, other fields, name, gender, and email all returned null.

For example:
SQL: SELECT * FROM Student;

In JPA Project, I got the following results:

```
ID Name   Gender Email
1  John   M      john@example.com
2  Emma   F      emma@example.com
```

In Web Project, I got the following results:

```
ID Name   Gender Email
1  null   null   null
2  null   null   null
```

Below is the source code of Student entity class.

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.String;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Student()
    {
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender()
    {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Comment: is StudentDomain class your DAO or entity ?

Comment: What is DAO? StudentDomain is not an entity class. It is where I write functions to query Student table like getStudentByName(), getStudentByGender().

Comment: DAO -> Data Access Object (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)

Comment: Try the JPQL of entityManager.createQuery("SELECT x FROM Student x") and see what you get. My guess is there's a type-o. Post the SQL/full code. This doesn't give enough to troubleshoot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version are you using?  If this is a native SQL query you are executing, it could be a case sensitivity issue on the column metadata returned from the query.  Depending on the EclipseLink version, you can try setting the persistence property "eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names" to true (add in EclipseLink 2.1), or upgrade to the latest version where it is true by default.

You might also try making sure the case of the fields defined in the column annotations matches what is returned from the database - the ID column is mapped to "ID" while the others are all in lower case, which might be a problem on databases returning upper case columns by default.

This would only be an issue with native SQL.  You could also try using a JPQL query such as em.createQuery("Select s from Student s") instead.

Comment: MySQL isn't that picky about case on column names so that shouldn't be it, ID would return "ID" as the field name and `id` would return "id" which matches.

Comment: MySQL isn't the problem, Java is.  If MySQL is returning the column name as "GENDER", using "gender" will not get the value from the returned results which get hashed based on the column String.  This is why JPQL might work, as EclipseLink controls the column positions, but in a native SQL query where it must use the column name to look up values in the returned results, there are problems with case.  The problem is the entity has the ID, but not the other fields with columns defined in lower case, and he mentions "select *" which only occurs with native SQL queries, not JPQL

Comment: I completely agree. I was looking at it backwards (I blame .NET MVC for messing with my train of thought). The statement `SELECT ID, name, gender, email FROM Students` would probably do it. It is the * that is screwing up the binding because MySQL defaults to whatever is in the database on the result-set (and columns can have different cases event though they are case-insensitive).

Comment: Nice.. Finally it worked with JPQL after I changed it to createQuery from createNativeQuery and the query statement to "SELECT s FROM Student s". Before that I tried other alternatives and found that NativeQuery is case-sensitive, ID is different to id. "SELECT ID, name, gender, email FROM Student" does not work either. So JPQL is the solution! Thank you very much guys.